# URL Path Parameter Encoding

Tags: java, tomcat, encoding, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm struggling with path param encoding with retrofit:

- `http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1` is my base url.
- I have this Call `@GET("path/{documentPath}")
  Call<Document> fetchDocumentByPath(@Path("documentPath") String docPath);`
- As param, I'm setting the following: `default-domain/blabla`
- I run the query against my tomcat app and I get this answer

`Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=400, message=Bad Request, url=http://localhost:8080/nuxeo/api/v1/path/default-domain%2Fblabla}`

- Even if I put encode = true to say "don't encode my parameter, it's already encoded", it's still encoding it.
- Moreover, in retrofit, this test `retrofit2.RequestBuilderTest#getWithEncodedPathParam` doesn't work if we put `Request request = buildRequest(Example.class, "po/ng");` with the following assertion: `assertThat(request.url().toString()).isEqualTo("http://example.com/foo/bar/po/ng/");`

**Tomcat has restricted his URL validation for security reason: http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2007-0450.**

**So I'd like to send '/' directly in my path parameter without encoding it in %2F. How can I achieve it?**

Thank you!

Comment: I'm using this version `parent-2.0.0-beta3`

Comment: Apparently it's fixed in beta4. I don't know what is the related bug and fix. Will confirm once tests are done globally on my side.

Comment: Confirmed. The usage of encoded = true is working properly now with the parent-2.0.0-beta4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `parent-2.0.0-beta4`, the parameter of the annotation of `@Path` is now working properly.